# Azure App Service "Could not find service certificate" when it is there

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-app-service, wif, acs

I have an Azure App Service that uses ACS to log in, it is an MVC 5 site if that helps at all.

It needs a certificate, let's say the thumbprint is **AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47**

I uploaded it via the portal:[image]

Then I added the Application Setting > App Setting of WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES/*:
[image]

Works great locally (of course) - when I load it up on Azure, I get:

> Could not find service certificate:
>   AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47AF47in the My store on
>   CurrentUser HandlingInstanceID: 74429bcf-4e02-4e28-a261-329bf831f7ce
>   An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred and was
>   caught.
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 06/27/2017 22:21:44 Type : System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Message : Value cannot be null.

(Stack trace unavailable)

Any idea what I am missing?  I have tried loading the certificate in my *Application_Start()* as well with no luck - I can post that code if anyone wants.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?  I have exactly the same problem and I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you’d like to upload your certificate to the certificates collection in Azure app service web app and consume it in your MVC application from your site’s personal certificate store, I upload a certificate and add an app setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES, and than I can access the certificate in my application using the following code, please refer to it.

```
var thumbprint = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

X509Certificate2 retVal = null;

X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

if (certCollection.Count > 0)
{
    retVal = certCollection[0];
}

certStore.Close();
```

**[remote debug web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) and it works as expected.**

[image]

Besides, [this article](https://msftplayground.com/2016/11/using-certificates-azure-app-services/) explained with detailed steps using Certificates in Azure App Services, please refer to it.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, but it appears to be in My store of CurrentUser, but NOT My store of LocalMachine

Comment: It is always loaded in the **CurrentUser** store as explained in the article shared by Fred. You cannot access LocalMachine store eitherways as the application doesn't have the permissions to do so.